# Failed to download repository information in update manager

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Details

```
W:Failed to fetch *http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch *http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch *http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonls/redshift-ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Whats causing this and how to fix it?

Ty

Regards

Answer (score 2):

`jonls/redshift-ppa` looks to be removed. run:

`sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:jonls/redshift-ppa` to remove it.

Comment: You're welcome :) A deb download is available here :http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/x11/redshift if you need the package in future by the way.